# how to write hibernate criteria query for two different tables

Tags: hibernate, join, criteria

I have these two classes

@Table(name="candidateinfo")

**Class CandidateInfo**{

....
@OneToMany

CandidateResume candidate;
....

}

@Table(name="candidateResume")

**Class CandidateResume**{
....

@ManyToOne

CandidateInfo candidates;

.......

}

Now i want to add two restrictoins from 2 different classes(as above) in the below criteria

for this i have

**Criteria  crit = session.createCriteria(CandidateResumeInfo.class);**

**crit.add(Restrictions.eq("resumeSearchable", 1))**;// resumeSearchable is in CandidateResume

**crit.createCriteria("candidate")**

**.add(Restrictions.eq("userid",1));**              // userid is in CandidateInfo Class

**List rsList = crit.list();** // At this line it goes to exception and not giving any error

for(Iterator it=rsList.iterator(); it.hasNext();)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please explain what exactly are you trying to search but if I understand you correctly you want to search for all results where canditate id = 1 and candidateresume. searchable = 1;

Then you need to make something like the following following query:

```
String query= "from Candidate c join c.candidate resume where c.userid = :userid and resume.resumeSearchable =: searchable";   
Query q = session.createQuery(query);
q.addInteger("userid",1);
q.addInteger("searchable",1);
List<Candidate> = q.list();
```

Comment: Thanks , yes you are right  i want to search for all results where canditate id = 1 and candidateresume. searchable = 1; 

but the problem is that candidateid is in one table i.e CandidateInfo and searchable is in other table i.e candidateResumeInfo     ,so how the compiler in your above solution will know which attribute is from which table(class)

Comment: This is the Hibernate problem not yours. As soon as you map all your classes correctly all tables are transparent for you. you are working with classes only. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Hibernate/Relation-One-to-Many.htm

Comment: Thanks , the link you mentioned is not using annotation   whereas i am using Annotation ,you have any idea how to use mapping in annotation for this scenario  , as i have used   like              Class CandidateResumeInfo {                                          @OneToOne                                                          CandidateInfo candidate;                                        is that all i have to do ?    thanks

Comment: You can search google, but this can help. http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-one-using-annotations-1.html